# Is storing the session_id in the session a valid method of preventing session attacks?

Tags: php, session

I have read this code on the php wiki but I am not convinced it is actually adding protection

```
Login code fragment: Code that adds session ID as validation key.

session_destory();
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['valid_id'] = session_id();
```

This validation part below is what I am not sure about:

```
Validation code: Code other than login. Check if session is properly initilized.

if ($_SESSION['valid_id'] !== session_id()) {
  die('Invalid use of session ID');
}
```

Because session_id() returns the session_id of the current session, why would session_id() not be identically equal to $_SESSION['valid_id'] for a given logged in session?

Can someone explain if the above code is effective?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default, PHP's file-based session handler uses the session ID as part of the filename that the session data is stored in. Storing the ID inside the session data itself would be somewhat redundant.

At best the code snippet would simply verify that the session was properly initialized by your own code, and isn't just some random session that got attached somehow to this user. But ANY key/value pair you store in the session could be used for that - it doesn't have to be the session ID at all. e.g. checking for this:

```
$_SESSION['everything is ok'] = "Yay, it's working"
```

would be just as good.